# Combining two columns in a select won't work

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, ms-access-2007, coldfusion-8

I need to combine values from 2 columns in a simple select statement using Access 2007 and ColdFusion 8. When I ran my query in Access I got the result without a problem, but when I put the query below in ColdFusion it won't run:

```
    <cfquery name="Maj" datasource="#application.dsn#">
     SELECT Majors & " " & GradeLevel 
     FROM Programs
     WHERE Categories = 'Language'
     ORDER BY Majors
    </cfquery>
```

It produces the following error:

```
The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

The error occurred in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test.cfm: line 4

    2 : 
    3 : 
    4 :         <cfquery name="Maj" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    5 :         SELECT Majors & " " & GradeLevel 
    6 :         FROM Programs
```

Answer (score 3):

Use single instead of double quotes around the space you're adding between `Majors` and `GradeLevel`.

```sql
SELECT Majors & ' ' & GradeLevel 
FROM Programs
WHERE Categories = 'Language'
ORDER BY Majors
```

If your next issue is how to alias that field expression, the Access db engine may object when you use an existing field name as the alias.  Avoid that problem by choosing an alias which doesn't match any of the field names.

```sql
SELECT Majors & ' ' & GradeLevel AS Majors_GradeLevel
```

Comment: That works thank you! but I can't use "AS" and I have trouble refering this result. I can't do select Majors & ' ' & GradeLevel AS Majors

Comment: Thank you! so I can only use name other than column name that's been used in the select?

Comment: Often using a field name as the alias for a field expression causes Access to complain about a "recursive alias".  Since you have Access, you can test the revised version of your query directly there to see whether it objects.

Comment: In some databases you can use a column name as an alias, but if you then want to use that column in your where clause, you are in trouble.

Comment: Or just do the SELECT on both Majors and GradeLevel and then concatenate them inside your display code rather than in your database call.